# Is there a way to have a regExp that cover two different kind of Dates?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I found several answers here that covers similar kind of dates but not different ones.

For example I would like to have a RegExp that matches both cases:

```
2017-07-28T06:33:45.206Z
Tue Jul 25 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
28-7-2017
```

Not as strings and numbers of course but as dates.

I'm using Reactive Forms so I'm using the `Validator.pattern(myRegExp)` so that would be very convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternation (`|`):

```
/optiona|optionb/
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

> `x|y`
>
> Matches either 'x' or 'y'.
>
> For example, `/green|red/` matches 'green' in "green apple" and 'red' in "red apple."

The operands to `|` are fairly greedy, but you may well need groups (probably non-capturing ones) around the alternatives, e.g.:

```
/(?:optiona)|(?:optionb)/
```

...depending on how you write it.

Comment: Is there an example for those 3 dates online? Actually I found only of the third one.

Comment: @VassilisPits: What, examples of the regexes to match them? Almost certainly, it's a very well-covered subject. I don't happen to know of any, though.

Comment: Thx. I cannot only find for the Second one `Tue Jul 28  201 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)`